# How to extend column in Azure App Insight log query which contains space and brackets in the column name?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to write a query to fetch some of the data from the Azure Application Insight, and what I want to do is there's one field inside that log which I want to extend it as a separate column, but while trying to run the query with that exported column in giving syntax error.

> Column Name: Request Duration (milliseconds)

Query:

```
customEvents
| extend Request_Duration_(milliseconds)_ = tostring(parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.Properties)).["Request Duration (milliseconds)"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your query, please try the code below:

```
customEvents 
| where name == "e2" 
| extend Request_Duration_milliseconds = parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.Properties)).["Request Duration (milliseconds)"]
| project customDimensions, Request_Duration_milliseconds
```

Test result:

[image]